# Composition of OR statements does not yield the correct boolean value when comparing strings

Tags: c++

I have the following code:

```
void funct(string m){
    if (m != "s" || m != "l" || m != "r" || m != "S" || m != "L" || m != "R") {
        //Do something
    }
}
```

When passed value "r" the conditional body should not be executed, due to m!="r". Anyways "Do something" is executed.

On the other side when testing the following statement

```
void funct(string m){
    if (m != "r") {
        //Do something
    }
}
```

Given m = "r" the function works as intended.

On the other hand, if use the == operator instead of !=  I get the correct composite value:

```
if (!(m == "l" || m == "l" || m == "r" || m == "S" || m == "L" || m == "R")) {
    //Do something
}
```

This works just fine.

Did anybody else have similar issues? Or explain the "misbehavior" of the first chunk of code.

Lang standard C++14

Grateful in advance

Comment: "not (a or b)" == "not a and not b", not "not a or not b".

Comment: false || true == true  so in your first test if anyone of the `!=` test is true then the whole expression is true.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's surprising that you can spell out the problem so clearly and yet not see the mistake you are making

```
if (m != "s" || m != "l" || m != "r" || m != "S" || m != "L" || m != "R") {
    //Do something
}
```

'Do something' will be executed if EITHER m != "s" OR if m != "l" OR ....

Since **every** string in the world is either not equal to `"s"` or not equal to `"l"` then 'do something' will **always** be executed. Think about it, `"s"` is not equal to `"l"` and `"l"` is not equal to `"s"` and every other string is not equal to both of them.

The code you really want is this

```
if (m != "s" && m != "l" && m != "r" && m != "S" && m != "L" && m != "R") {
    //Do something
}
```

To be fair this is an extremely common mistake to make in logic.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the C++ standard library functions to reduce mistakes. `std::none_of` from the `algorithm` header works great in this situation. If your string matches none of the other strings, it will return true.

```
#include <algorithm>

void funct(const string& m) {
    const string tokens[] = {"s", "l", "r", "S", "L", "R"};
    auto compare = [&m](const string& token) { return m == token; };
    if (none_of(begin(tokens), end(tokens), compare)) {
        //Do something
    }
}
```